# Android Volley Singleton- requests not being sent to server (stuck in queue)

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-volley

I implemented Volley singleton (there are few examples over the internet) in order to use it from different activities. 
For some reason, requests are not being sent to server, and when I inspect it on debug mode it looks that there are waiting in the volley request queue.

This is my singleton:

```
public class VolleyInternetOperator
{
    private static VolleyInternetOperator mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private VolleyInternetOperator(Context context)
    {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized VolleyInternetOperator getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleyInternetOperator(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }


    public static synchronized VolleyInternetOperator getInstance()
    {
        if (null == mInstance)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(VolleyInternetOperator.class.getSimpleName() +
                    " is not initialized, call getInstance(...) first");
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }


    public interface responseFunctionInterface
    {
        void apply(JSONObject response, JSONObject params);
    }

    public interface errorFunctionInterface
    {
        void apply(VolleyError error, JSONObject params);
    }



    public void accessWebsiteWithVolley(String url, int requestMethod,
            final JSONObject params, final HashMap<String, String> additionalHeaders,
            final responseFunctionInterface responseFunction, final errorFunctionInterface errorFunction)
    {

        CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest =
                new CustomJSONObjectRequest(requestMethod, url, params,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Log.d("got", "response");
                                responseFunction.apply(response, params);
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d("error", error.toString());
                                errorFunction.apply(error, params);
                            }
                        })
                {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        if (null != additionalHeaders) {
                            Iterator it = additionalHeaders.entrySet().iterator();
                            while (it.hasNext()) {
                                HashMap.Entry<String, String> pair = (Map.Entry<String, String>) it.next();
                                headers.put(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                        return headers;

                    }
                };
        addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest);
    }
}
```

I initialized it in the main activity onCreate:

```
VolleyInternetOperator.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
```

In order to send jsonRequest I'm using the following code:

```
VolleyInternetOperator.getInstance().accessWebsiteWithVolley(url, requestMethod, null, headers,responseFunction, errorFunction);
```

The request works when I copy the relevant parts to my activity, so I guess it's related to the singleton.

Thanks!

Edit 1:

Apparently it works if I'm calling the singleton from within my main activity, but if I create an object (I have dataCollector object) that calls it, it doesn't work.